# Paste from clipboard in Android

Tags: java, android, clipboard

I wrote a code which copies an answer in calculator to clipboard, then calculator is closed and another window is opened. The answer should be pasted here using code:

```
    textOut2= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etInput1);
    final ClipboardManager clipBoard= (ClipboardManager)getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
    textOut2.setText(clipBoard.getText());
```

but it never works. WHere could be a mistake? p.s. I know what text is copied because I can paste using long press but I want to do it automaticaly. And is it possible to give a specific name for a copied text? As it would make it easier to paste words as I have a lot of different TextView's

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> public CharSequence getText ()
>   Since: API Level 11
>   This method is deprecated.
>   Use getPrimaryClip() instead. This retrieves the primary clip and tries to coerce it to a string.

```
String textToPaste = null;

ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager)getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);

if (clipboard.hasPrimaryClip()) {
    ClipData clip = clipboard.getPrimaryClip();

    // if you need text data only, use:
    if (clip.getDescription().hasMimeType(MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN))
        // WARNING: The item could cantain URI that points to the text data.
        // In this case the getText() returns null and this code fails!
        textToPaste = clip.getItemAt(0).getText().toString();

    // or you may coerce the data to the text representation:
    textToPaste = clip.getItemAt(0).coerceToText(this).toString();
}

if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(textToPaste))
     ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.etInput1)).setText(textToPaste);
```

You are allowed to add additional `ClipData.Item` items with text via `ClipData.addItem()`, but there is no way to discern them.

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
textOut2= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etInput1);
final ClipboardManager clipBoard= (ClipboardManager)getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
String temp = new String;
temp = clipBoard.getText().toString();
textOut2.setText(temp);
```

Answer (score 1):

In Kotlin:

```
        val clipboard = (getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE)) as? ClipboardManager
        val textToPaste = clipboard?.primaryClip?.getItemAt(0)?.text ?: return

        binding.<your EditText camelCase id>.setText(textToPaste)
```

Inside Fragment: getSystemService() is a method on the Context class and it's necessary to call Context first. It's possible by either using getContext() or alternatively, the getActivity() - Activity is also a Context.

```
this.activity.getSystemService(...)
this.context.getSystemService(...)
```

Or:

```
activity.getSystemService(...)
context.getSystemService(...)
```

Plus remember about only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls.